# How do i find the following text from a text file in batch script?

Tags: bash

Ive been banging my head against a wall trying to work this out.

```
{
"FleetAttributes": {
    "FleetId": "fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05",
    "FleetArn": "arn:aws:gamelift:us-west-2:321110313936:fleet/fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05",
    "FleetType": "ON_DEMAND",
    "InstanceType": "c4.large",
    "Description": "Development build of Project Genesis",
    "Name": "ProjectGenesis-DevelopmentBuild",
    "CreationTime": 1560297730.139,
    "Status": "NEW",
    "BuildId": "build-0f8b9c4f-56a3-48e3-af28-018383af8fd1",
    "NewGameSessionProtectionPolicy": "FullProtection",
    "OperatingSystem": "WINDOWS_2012",
    "ResourceCreationLimitPolicy": {
        "NewGameSessionsPerCreator": 4,
        "PolicyPeriodInMinutes": 15
    },
    "MetricGroups": [
        "default"
    ]
}
```

The above is the contents of the text file. Im trying to extract the FleetId in batch script to put it in a variable so i can use it later for another command.

Ive tried findstr and regex but its so limited it appears useless.

What options do i have to find the `fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05` text and put it in a var?

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/sELP6Y/1)

The above regex sample is sufficient to find it but i cant use it with findstr because its support for extended characters is dismal.

Comment: Can you load the linux shell in your windows install?  It's stupid easy to do in most unix shells using grep and awk.

Comment: What would a shell script look like to do what i need?

Comment: What OS are you using? note that tag [tag:batch-file] is Windows-related...

Comment: @aschipfl I feel is Windows related because of the `findstr` in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you asked in your comments what a bash script might look like:

```
for thing in `grep 'FleetId' yourfile.txt | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | tr -d '" ,'`; do
   # do something with the id as $thing
   echo $thing
done
```

Comment: That's definitely not what a bash script to do anything would look like, it contains several bugs and anti-patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your input looks like json - if it is json then you should be using a json parser on it like `jq`, e.g. after fixing your sample input file to be valid json by just adding a terminating `}`:

```
$ cat file
{
"FleetAttributes": {
    "FleetId": "fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05",
    "FleetArn": "arn:aws:gamelift:us-west-2:321110313936:fleet/fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05",
    "FleetType": "ON_DEMAND",
    "InstanceType": "c4.large",
    "Description": "Development build of Project Genesis",
    "Name": "ProjectGenesis-DevelopmentBuild",
    "CreationTime": 1560297730.139,
    "Status": "NEW",
    "BuildId": "build-0f8b9c4f-56a3-48e3-af28-018383af8fd1",
    "NewGameSessionProtectionPolicy": "FullProtection",
    "OperatingSystem": "WINDOWS_2012",
    "ResourceCreationLimitPolicy": {
        "NewGameSessionsPerCreator": 4,
        "PolicyPeriodInMinutes": 15
    },
    "MetricGroups": [
        "default"
    ]
}
}
```

and wrapping `jq` in a shell script and saving it's output in a variable as you requested:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

tag="$1"
file="$2"

var=$(jq --arg tag "$tag" -r '.FleetAttributes[$tag]' "$file")

printf '%s\n' "$var"

$ ./tst.sh FleetId file
fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05

$ ./tst.sh BuildId file
build-0f8b9c4f-56a3-48e3-af28-018383af8fd1
```

Otherwise if your input isn't really json or you can't install a tool like `jq` that understands json then awk would be your next best bet:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

tag="$1"
file="$2"

var=$(awk -v tag="$tag" '$1=="\""tag"\":"{sub(/",?$/,""); sub(/.*"/,""); print}' "$file")

printf '%s\n' "$var"

$ ./tst.sh FleetId file
fleet-ad6061f3-6eaa-4a07-b68e-1042f1288e05

$ ./tst.sh BuildId file
build-0f8b9c4f-56a3-48e3-af28-018383af8fd1
```

but that would need significant changes to be able to do this:

```
$ jq -r .FleetAttributes.ResourceCreationLimitPolicy file
{
  "NewGameSessionsPerCreator": 4,
  "PolicyPeriodInMinutes": 15
}

$ jq -r .FleetAttributes.MetricGroups file
[
  "default"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Windows cmd,

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:," %A IN ('findstr "FleetId" [name_json_file.json]') DO echo %A
```

Inside a batch file,

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:," %%A IN ('findstr "FleetId" [name_json_file.json]') DO echo %%A

pause
::
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified @PaulProgrammer suggestion to allow for arguments.

```
for id in `grep "$1" $2 | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | tr -d '" ,'`; do
   echo $id >> "$1"Temp.txt
done
```

This allows me to pass 2 arguments as follows.

```
GameLiftIdHelper.sh FleetId TestFleetId.txt
GameLiftIdHelper.sh "Build ID" TestBuildId.txt
```

Comment: No. Don't do that.